# Getting a " Error: locator.click: Target page, context or browser has been closed" when running a playwright test

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { HelperCommands } from '../commands/helper';
import path from 'path';

// Before each test we need to initialize some variables
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
const helper = new HelperCommands(page);
await helper.goToHomePage();
});

test.describe("Test 5 ", async () => {

test('Test101', async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
    const helper = new HelperCommands(page);
    await helper.setUpAccount();
    await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: /^20$/ }).first().click();
    await page.getByRole('dialog').getByText('Verify').last().click();
    await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: /^I Agree$/ }).first().click();
    await helper.goToWallet()
    await page.locator('.add-btn').click();
    fileChooserPromise = page.waitForEvent('filechooser');
    await page.getByText('Upload file').last().click();
    var fileChooser2 = await fileChooserPromise;
    await fileChooser2.setFiles(path.join(__dirname, './assets/logo.png'));
    await page.getByRole('dialog').getByText('Save').click();
    await page.getByText('Sports').click();

    // Complete the mandatory fields
      await page.getByPlaceholder('Give a name').fill('Tests');
      await page.getByPlaceholder('Provide a detailed description of the item').fill('TestText');
      await page.locator('.textarea').nth(1).fill('Test Content');
      await page.getByPlaceholder('https://example.com').fill('https://www.example.com');

    // Continue to the next step
    await page.getByText('Next').click();
    await page.getByRole('dialog').getByText('Confirm').click();

    //Click on Finish button
    await page.getByText('Finish').click();
    await expect(page).toHaveURL('https://example.com');
    await page.locator('.sealing-btn').first().click();
    await page.waitForLoadState()
    await page.getByText('Finish').nth(1).click();
  
});
```

[AfterAll Hook runs in the middle of the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2JoW.png)

I have written a test like above using playwright. But after clicking the "Next" button, the After hooks runs randomly and then the test is closed.

The error message is displayed.
I have not used AfterAll hook but get this 'Error: locator.click: Target page, context or browser has been closed' every time after clicking Next button.

Need help with this.

I was actually trying to run a long test case that contains long test path.

Comment: There are no clicks triggering navigations but as you can see in screenshot above the playwright captures the issues that displays the after hook in between the test.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I still don't see anything obviously wrong here, and I can't run it since I don't have your page under test, so a [mcve] would still be useful (emphasis on _minimal_--strip out all of the unnecessary parts that aren't actually contributing to the error and make it runnable, possibly with a sample page).